# Tire, Elastic Search and Delayed Job in Ruby on Rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, delayed-job, tire

I have some issues with integrating Rails. 3.2.13, Tire 0.6.0, Elastic Search 0.90.2 and Delayed Job 3.0.5.

When I try to postpone index action with delayed job, index is OK, but following search sort is ignored. If I reindex the whole index with rake environment tire:import:all, everything is OK.

My code:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

 #...getters/setters omitted...

 include Tire::Model::Search
 #include Tire::Model::Callbacks #don't use callback, we use delayed job indexing


 after_commit {tire.delay.update_index } #DELAYED JOB
 after_destroy {tire.delay.update_index } #DELAYED JOB

 mapping do
    indexes :id, :index    => :not_analyzed
    indexes :title
    indexes :is_open, type: 'boolean'
 end


 def self.search(params)
  tire.search(:page => (params[:page] || 1), load: true) do
   query { string params[:q], :default_operator=>"AND"} if params[:q].present?

   sort do
     by :is_open, "desc" #THIS SORT IS IGNORED WHEN I INDEX WITH DELAYED JOB, BUT IT WORKS WHEN I INDEX WITHOUT IT (WITH TIRE CALLBACKS OR WITH delay OMITTED).
   end

  end

end


end
```

Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Jiri Hradil